# How to fix "tuple object has no attribute"?

Tags: python

I'm doing a homework problem, and I keep getting an error that the tuple in the `__init__` function has no `age` attribute, but it does.

I've tried using the `x[y]` notation to try and solve this, but no luck.
Here's the code:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
time=2019
p1=(input("Name: "),input("Age: "))
clock=100-p1.age
time=time+clock
print("Hi "+ p1.name +"! You will turn 100 in "+ clock+"!")
```

Here's the message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    clock=100-p1.age
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'age'
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it ever reached the `__init__` method? You never referred to the name `Person` ever again after defining the class, so `__init__` would never be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p1=(input("Name: "),input("Age: "))
```

As of right now, you're making a 2-tuple, not a `Person`. This should be

```
p1 = Person(input("Name: "), input("Age: "))
```